# row duplication based on week day

Tags: mysql

I have a table with these fields:

```
ID; first_sunday_day; name; address; monday; tuesday; wednesday; thursday; friday; saturday; sunday
1; 20230812;test;myaddress;0;0;1;1;0;0;0
```

I need to duplicate this row as many times as the days with 1, and also change the day by adding as many days as the days I have 1 in it.

in my example first_sunday_day is the 12 of august and I have 1 under wednesday and thursday. So what I need to receive is:

```
Name;address;newdate;
test;myaddress;20230815
test;myaddress;20230816
```

How can I achieve this with a query?
Thank you

Comment: Just of note, be aware that although using UnixTimestamp is easier to handle mathematically with date comparisons, just be aware that number system runs out of numbers in the year 2038 and will likely completely break any script that relies on it to do date calculations.

Comment: But I'm not using Unix timestamp..am I?

Comment: The format seems very much like it could be is why I say that.  Granted one of the dates is from 53 years ago when converted, I will link a citation for you to check yourself at the end of this.   Now it doesn't have to be UnixTimestamp format per say, but the work around to compare dates is to put them into an integer format as such, then its just simple math to compare dates.

citation ->https://www.unixtimestamp.com/

Comment: I really think you misunderstood the problem. I don't need to compare the dates. I need some help in duplicating rows depending on what weekday I have set

Comment: I'm sorry I offered the advice as a comment and not an answer to the question.  It is just prewarning about a future possible problem.    Alas I don't have the exact answer for this unfortunately.